# What is the =::=::\\ variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm on Windows 10, I was scrolling through my environment variables to change something, and in the list I see `"=::=::\\"`. For reference, a more reasonable one looks like `"LOCALAPPDATA=C:\\Users\\Timeroot\\AppData\\Local"`. Of course this string of colons and punctuation is basically ungoogleable, and I'm not even sure how to parse it. (Does it break at the first equals sign or the second? Are you allowed to name a variable "=::"?)

I'm curious if anyone has any insight into what this means or what program might have set it, and why.

Comment: Used by Windows Shell\Explorer.

Comment: @user2120666 Great, could you elaborate or give a source? What does it do? How does it parse?

Comment: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/